# How to show a list with ManyRelatedManager objects in nested serializer Django

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a Category model (Parent) and a Product model (Child) with a FK to Category.
Several products may belong to the same category and I want to show all products of a Category in GET request. But as a result, I get duplication of categories by the number of products.

For example:
If I have one category "Milk" and 3 products with FK to "Milk", my GET method returns 3 instances of Category.

my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        default_related_name = "product"

    category = models.ForeignKey(CatalogItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
```

my views.py

```
class CategoryApi(ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductCatalogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.all()
```

My serializers.py

```
class ProductCatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            "marketplaces",
        )

    marketplaces = serializers.SerializerMethodField(help_text="category products info")


    @staticmethod
    @swagger_serializer_method(serializer_or_field=serializers.ListField)
    def get_marketplaces(obj):
        results_data = MarketplaceInProductSerializer(list(obj.product.all()), many=True).data
# results_data is a list with ordered dicts
        return results_data


class MarketplaceInProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(help_text="ID продукта")
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(help_text="Категория")

    @staticmethod
    @swagger_serializer_method(serializer_or_field=serializers.CharField)
    def get_name(data):
        return data.name
```

I want to get in response a list with existing categories and products in it.

Comment: I think I found the solution myself. Need to add a method .distinct() in get_queryset()